# I want to match all punctuation in my regexp except apostrophes. How do i do that in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

This is my code so far:

```
def alternate_words(string)
    string.gsub(/[\p{P}]/, "")
end
```

I am looking for a way to add exceptions to my regular expressions. Is it possible or do I have to list them all out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string = "jack. o'reilly? mike??!?"
puts string.gsub(/[\p{P}&&[^']]/, '')
# => jack o'reilly mike
```

[Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes):

> A character class may contain another character class. By itself this isn’t useful because `[a-z[0-9]]` describes the same set as `[a-z0-9]`. However, character classes also support the `&&` operator which performs set intersection on its arguments.

So, `[\p{P}&&[^']]` is "any character that is punctuation and also not an apostrophe".

Comment: other way: `[^\P{P}']`

Comment: Yup, @CasimiretHippolyte's solution should work too.